# friend function in php?

Tags: php

Does php support friend function like as c++ supports?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't: http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=friend+function+php and even Wikipedia seems doesn't mention it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_function

Comment: not find friend but c++ supports friend class or function\

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP equivalent of friend or internal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/317835/php-equivalent-of-friend-or-internal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are most likely referring to class/variable scope. In php, you have:

- public
- private
- protected

But not `friend` visibility. The `protected` though is used when an object's members are to be made visible only to other extending/inheriting objects.

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Answer (score 3):

No. You have to declare it public.

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't support any friend-like declarations. It's possible to simulate this using the PHP5 __get and __set methods and inspecting a backtrace for only the allowed friend classes, although the code to do it is kind of clumsy.

There's some sample code and discussion on the topic on PHP's site:

class HasFriends
{
    private $__friends = array('MyFriend', 'OtherFriend');

```
public function __get($key)
{
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    if(isset($trace[1]['class']) && in_array($trace[1]['class'], $this->__friends)) {
        return $this->$key;
    }

    // normal __get() code here

    trigger_error('Cannot access private property ' . __CLASS__ . '::$' . $key, E_USER_ERROR);
}

public function __set($key, $value)
{
    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    if(isset($trace[1]['class']) && in_array($trace[1]['class'], $this->__friends)) {
        return $this->$key = $value;
    }

    // normal __set() code here

    trigger_error('Cannot access private property ' . __CLASS__ . '::$' . $key, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

}