# Class function only available to "parent" - PHP

Tags: php, oop, class

I want to create a  function in a class that is available for a set of users, but that they won't be able to access. Ex:

```
class Stuff_for_user {
     private $errors;
     /* 
     *  private $errors gets modified by private functions
     */

     public function get_errors(){  // This is for users to display errors.
          return $this->errors;
     }

     /*something here...*/ function set_errors($str){
          $this->errors = $str; 
     }
}
```

So far so good, but now I want the parent class to be able to set `Stuff_for_User`'s errors:

```
 class Main_mess {
     public index(){ 
          $user_available_data = new  Stuff_for_user();

          if($big_error)
              $user_available_data->set_errors("BIG ERROR!!!"); 

          $this->send_to_users($user_available_data);
     }
}
```

I want only `Main_mess` to be able to access `Stuff_for_User`'s `set_errors()` method. Is that possible?

Comment: I guess you are looking for a `friend`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707409/friend-function-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for implementation of something called [friend class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class) in php. Well .. i'm sorry to tell you this, but **it is not possible**.

You should look at other possible solutions to your problem.

```
class SecureContainer{

   protected $user = null;
   protected $target = null;

   public function __construct( $target, $user )
   {
      $this->target = $target;
      $this->user = $user;
   }

   public function __call( $method, $arguments )
   {
      if ( $this->user->isAllowed(getType( $this->target ), $method))
      {
         return call_user_func_array( 
            array( $this->target, $method), $arguments );
      }
   }

}
```

Use it like this:

```
$something = new UnsecureSomething;
$user = new User( $uid );
$something = new SecureContainer( $something, $user );
```

This should let you control the access to methods.

Comment: PHP shouldn't call itself an OO Language then... #Failhard.

Comment: Ill try this, but I needed something sooo simple that PHP should make available. More bloat for me...

Comment: @localhost2 , it is easy to contribute new stuff .. you are welcome to submit proposals and implement them .. oh, and btw, C++ is the **only** language with friend class concept, and it is widely regarded as harmful because of tight coupling.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to change the design to something more robust and actually look at the bigger picture, instead of making a quick fix.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible like that, since `Main_mess` is not a parent class of `Stuff_for_users` (and this is probably what you want, looking at what your code actually does). So `set_errors` has to be `public` if you want to call it from the outside.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible how you want to implement it.

Some ideas (i dont know why or how you want to do that but just ideas...):

do `set_error($str,$access_key)` and let $access_key be an access string only you know!
let Stuff_for_user be in `Extended_Stuff_for_user` which has the set_error function like:

```
class Extended_Stuff_for_user {
  private $errors;
  private $Stuff_for_user;

  public function set_errors() {
      /* ... */
  }

  public function getStuffForUser() {
     return $this->Stuff_for_user;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ar you aware what your solution is breaking both SRP and LSP  ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible but it can be dirty.

Like This.

```
class Stuff_for_user {
     private $errors;
     /* 
     *  private $errors gets modified by private functions
     */

     public function get_errors(){  // This is for users to display errors.
          return $this->errors;
     }

       /* 
          This way the child classes of Main will able be to use the set_errors function;
       */
     function set_errors($class,$str){
          if($class instanceof Main_mess) 
           { 
             $this->errors = $str; 
           }

       /* 
       AndThis way the only Main_mess will be able;
       */
         function set_errors($class,$str){
          if(get_class($class)=="Main_mess") 
           { 
             $this->errors = $str; 
           }

     }


class Main_mess {
     public index(){ 
          $user_available_data = new  Stuff_for_user();

          if($big_error)
              $user_available_data->set_errors($this,"BIG ERROR!!!"); 

          $this->send_to_users($user_available_data);
     }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's another solution. But the base problem stays the same. As a user I could just do new Main_mess() und push it to set_error. It's dirty in <anyway>