# PHP friend/package visibility

Tags: php, package, visibility, friend

Is there any way to limit the visibility in PHP in the same way as "package" visibility works in Java or at least "friend" visibility in C++? What's the best practice to maintain large OOP project and not to let anyone use any part of code?

I use private and protected visibility as much as I can but sometimes it's not enough. I know about this request: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55331. Is there any progress in implementing such thing to PHP? Is there any workaround to protect your code (methods, class variables) from being accessed from anywhere?

Comment: Not exactly like packages in Java, but [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) will serve for code encapsulation.

Comment: Could you type a short example, please?

Comment: Just a thought, if you really needed to you could use `debug_backtrace` [http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php] to see what code is calling your code. Essentially writing your own runtime access control. Probably more work than it's worth, and the `debug_backtrace` has a performance hit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP equivalent of friend or internal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317835/php-equivalent-of-friend-or-internal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287315/can-php-namespaces-contain-variables):

> No. You can set a variable after declaring a namespace, but variables
>   will always exist in the global scope. They are never bound to
>   namespaces. You can deduce that from the absence of any name
>   resolution descriptions in
>   http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Howerver, I'd still like to know some best practices or workarounds to achieve some protection of your code.

Comment: I don't see how this answers OP's question. Namespaces have nothing to do with access visibility.

Comment: @Markus I agree that this old answer of mine doesn't explicitly address it, but it says that (contrary to just a variable) everything in any namespace is global, hence that you have no way to hide members using access modifiers like "private" or "protected".

Answer (score 9):

Until today there's no language construct to limit the visibility. But you can annotate your class with phpDocumentor's [`@internal`](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/internal.html):

> The `@internal` tag can be used as counterpart of the `@api` tag, indicating that the associated Structural Elements are used purely for the internal workings of this piece of software.

It's up to the API user to follow that suggestion.