# Full OOP in PHP - internal methods

Tags: php, oop

Is there any professional way to set the visibility of a method to internal/package inside my namespace?

Example:

```
namespace ExampleFramework;

class Request {
   ...

   public function getResponse() {
       return new Response(...); // Should work
   }
}

class Response {
   internal function __construct(...) {
      ...
   }
}

namespace AnotherFramework;

$request = new Request();
$response = $request->getResponse(); // Should work
$wrongResponse = new Response(...); // Should NOT work
```

Comment: No, PHP doesn't have that.

Comment: "professional" just means you get paid to do it nothing more.

Comment: Also to me it looks like you are something very not OOP. So soncidering you tagged it OOP: *why* on earth are you trying to do this?

Comment: I can tell you why: it's normal in frameworks that there are classes which only can be created (the objects) by framework-intern classes, for example an XMLReader which gives you the XML-structure as an object of the class XMLElement. The framwork calls methods like addAttribute(...) or addChild(...), but the user of the framwork should only be able to "read" like getAttributes() and so on, but NOT manipulate it. So the "write"-methods are not public nor private, they must be internal/package.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't simply talking about private / protected setters and public getters??

Comment: And how can the XMLReader-class set (add) a XML-attribute of the XMLElemet-object if its setter's is private or protected?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP friend/package visibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292433/php-friend-package-visibility)

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't have a language construct to enforce that visibility. IMO the best you can do is use phpDocumentor's [`@internal`](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/internal.html) and hope that the API user follow's the contract:

> The `@internal` tag can be used as counterpart of the `@api` tag, indicating that the associated Structural Elements are used purely for the internal workings of this piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use private constructor in `Response` class:

```
class Request {
   ...

   public function getResponse() {
       return Response::getInstance(...);
   }
}

class Response {

  private function __construct(...) {
  }

  public static getInstance(...) {
    return new Response(...);
  }

}
```

Comment: Yes but this is no guarantee that it's internal. I just can write $wrongResponse = Response::getInstance() and it works, no matter where I type it. Furthermore there can be multiple responses, not just one. So Singleton is not very helpful in this case.

Comment: Only thing you can do is to use reflections and check what called your method. But this is very heavyweight solution.

Comment: @LucaNateMahler this pattern is not a singleton because it creates new object every time.

Comment: Yes you're right. But there is no difference between this and a normal constructor because it's also public.

Comment: @hsz That may be the case but it has the exact same problems as a singleton and therefor has no place in OOP

Answer (score 0):

Looks like package visibility. But php has none. :^ )

You could use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace). For example

```
namespace One
    {

    class Request
        {

        public function getResponse()
            {
            return new Response();
            }

        }

    class Response
        {

        public function __construct()
            {
            $debug = debug_backtrace();
            if (count($debug) < 2 
                || !isset($debug[1]['class']) 
                || strpos($debug[1]['class'], __NAMESPACE__ . '\\') !== 0)
                {
                die('Invalid context');
                }
            echo 'Created' . PHP_EOL;
            }

        }

    }

namespace Two
    {
    $request = new \One\Request();
    $response = $request->getResponse(); // Should work
    $wrongResponse = new \One\Response(); // Should NOT work
    }
```

http://3v4l.org/g0dnG#v530